# Validating username uniqueness

Tags: java, spring

So I have been put a lot of thought into ways of validating if username is uniqe for new users or if changing it for existing user. My main concern would be performance as user data can be uploaded through csv and I believe making 1000 queries for validation (assuming 1k uploads) is not a good way.

For now I am mocking the repository implementation, real data is accesses through soap. I am looking for any suggestions for making this validation. I have done something already that kind of works by querying all users and looping the list, but the code looks kinda ugly. Application is on latest Spring. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on how you do the uniqueness-checking, it could be possible to check for a bunch of names at once (e.g. 20 names) in something like a `where username in (...)` query. If you find a duplicate within that, you can do the check for every single username to find the exact duplicate. But this depends on how you do the actual checking.

Comment: I don't use database. For testing the data is mocked. In production it comes through soap ws.

Answer (score 1):

I believe at some point you will have to go through each username and determine and perform the validation on that item to know if it should be rejected.

If I am understanding correctly you have an application that accepts your data and needs to validate it. That application makes a web service call to another application that has the data store?

If you have control over the web service API between the two applications you might consider changing to allow multiple records to be sent at a time. That would reduce the number of connections being made between the two applications.

As to to whether or not doing this the way you describe, or the way I suggest would make a significant different in performance I can't say. There are too many factors involved to really be sure until you actually use it.

Comment: Thanks. Well I haven't yet received their API endpoints so I unfortunately don't exactly know against what I am coding. The other backend has a data store yes. I am just looking to do the implementation on mock to be almost as perfect as it can be to later do the production implementation, which should look pretty much similar. Their backend probably would be able to validate it second time, but I prefer my backend to do it fine.